# How to add a hook to Nuxt routing using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get a hook into the Nuxt routing, so that I can do some magic before a page is loaded. However I cannot seem to find a TypeScript example on how to do this. The below example does not work:

```
<template>
    <div class="some-css">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue"

    export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
        text: string = "My Component"

        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next): void {
            console.log(`Routing from: ${ from }, to: ${ to }`)
            next()
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .some-css {
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>
```

Is there a way to do this either in this component or on a global level in Nuxt using TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I usually do it using nuxt-property-decorator:

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue"
import { Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from) {
    // do stuff
  }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

Comment: ah yeah i forgot to mention that i do use @Component, although it is the vue-property-decorator import

Comment: I have tried it and unfortunately it doesnt work...